# OpenStack instance name resolution

Tags: openstack

I have a private `OpenStack` cluster running on five machines (let's call them blade1-blade5).  Let's say I spin up ten instances named node01-node10. node01 through node06 spin up on blade1, then node07 through node10 each spin up with one instance on each of the remaining blades (node07 on blade2, node08 on blade3, etc). If I `ssh` into node01, I can `ping` any of the other instances spawned on blade1 using their instance names (e.g. `ping node03`), but if I try to `ping` one of the instances on another machine (e.g `ping node08`) I get an `unknown host` error. Similarly, if I `ssh` into one of the "singleton" instances, I can't ping any of the other instances using their names.  I *can* ping any instance from any other instance using an IP address.

Clearly, for whatever reason OpenStack is only resolving the names of instances spawned on the same machine. Is there a way to allow name resolution for *all* instances, regardless of what machine they're spawned on?

Comment: You have to set the same network config for  both openstack setups. Are you using nova-network?